# How to find all cells within a neighborhood with slopes towards the center?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, slope, direction, aspect

I would like to iteratively go through each cell in a raster in arcGIS that meets criteria (already established as per below description) and find the percentage of cells in a several km neighborhood with slopes pointing towards/away from the central cell (before moving onto the next cell, which would then become the central cell).

For a given raster of a region (let's say Europe so you have the idea of the extent of the dataset) I have created a map of all slopes above a certain degree. 
From this raster, I am calculating a ruggedness variable that applies to those slopes (effects things like wind speed) using focal statistics: percentage of cells in the specified neighborhood of each cell that is above that slope. But, the ruggedness variable does not truly capture this when it includes slopes that do not effect the wind.

An example would be that when looking in the direction due north of a specified cell, within the neighborhood, a slope is oriented east-west. While this has some effect on the wind, it is not the specific effect I am looking for. I would want to only look at slopes oriented north, northwest, northeast (to a certain limit) and south, southeast/west *that lie north (or south) of the central cell*, and then also for cells east or west of the cell, only slopes oriented east/west/etc.

I have the idea of using Aspect on the slopes meeting my criteria, which would give the angle of each cell. I thought about using Euclidean direction and iterating through each cell, defining that cell as the source, and then applying an equation to cells in the neighborhood (a few km) to determine if the aspect and euclidean direction match. However, in order to do this I would need to basically have a custom focal statistics tool.

Has anyone done something similar or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Size of Europe tells me nothing about raster size. Number of columns, rows does. I suggest making a picture with 3*3 mesh to show what you are after. It will replace 80% of your text.

Comment: Also with raster there are only 8 possible directions, so when your neighborhood is greater than 3*3 you'll be left with massive gaps between 4 remaining rays.

Comment: The data is a clip of Europe of the 7.5 arc second GMTED2010 DEM. I cannot take a screenshot of what I am working with due to my organization's policies. I am trying to replicate the RIX value calculation (ruggedness index, but not TRI) using arcGIS. RIX uses 72 radial lines of  about 3.5km to compute slope over a given threshhold (usually 30%) as a percentage of the neighborhood. However, its version of neighborhood is the 72 lines, and it does not include the gaps you mentioned. I have already reduced the GMTED DEM to slopes 30% or greater.